# Javascript multidimensional array syntax: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm really struggling to create a valid multidimensional JavaScript array with the following basic format:

```
var countries = [
  {
    "country": "UK",
    "properties": {"value1", "value2", "value3"}
  },
    "country": "Spain",
    "properties": {"value4", "value5", "value6"}
  }
]
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Well you need square brackets around your values. Are you getting an error?

Comment: your array declaration itself is wrong... please try to visit w3c schools atleast and get some js basics....
"country":"uk" what are try to do with this line ? trying make key value pair ? country as key and uk as value ???
and you missing some brackets too :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check the below:

```
var countries = [
  {
    "country": "UK",
    "properties": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
  },
  {
     "country": "Spain",
     "properties": ["value4", "value5", "value6"]
  }
]
```

`countries` is a array, which has 2 element, and the element is an object, whose `properties` looks like also an array, the array syntax is like `[1,2,3]`. And be sure `{` and `[` should be pair with `}` and `]`.

Comment: If they can't see the errors in their own code, they're not necessarily going to spot the difference in yours. Some indication of what they're doing wrong probably wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Thanks, I found this blindingly obvious bug myself and then went to delete my question... but it was too late. Can you tell I'm having a bad day?

Answer (score 4):

```
{"value1", "value2", "value3"}
```

If this is to be an array, the `{}` should be `[]`.

`{}` makes an object, which needs to be key/value pairs.

You're also missing a `{` before `"country": "Spain"`.

Comment: @jbabey...Actually Anthony Grist noticed that, I added that to my answer after reading his answer =/

Answer (score 2):

```
"properties": {"value1", "value2", "value3"}
```

This is an object which requires key / value pairs. So you can either do:

```
"properties": {"value1": "value1", "value2": "value2", "value3": "value3"}
```

(Which is kind of silly). Or you can use an array:

```
"properties": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `{` to indicate the start of the second object in the array.